# Unity: aligning object from multiple points to ground

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, position

I need to allow players to drag objects around the surface of my lowpoly ground so that the object sticks to the ground from certain points (in this case all the 6 legs). I tried Raycast to set position and rotation of the object with:

```
transform.position = hit.point;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation (Vector3.up, hit.normal);
```

This works quite nice but it always leaves some of the legs in the air because I set position and rotation of the whole transform not each leg individually. I could Raycast all of the legs individually but after that how can I position and rotate legs so that other parts of the model stays with the legs and the model doesn't "break".

Also I tried to give each leg a rigidbody and box collider but that just breaks the model by shooting the legs somewhere.

All ideas are welcome.

[image]
[image]

Comment: May be you can check those legs that have the largest distance to the ground and rotate the model in their direction?

Comment: What you're looking for is an inverse kinematics solver. Unfortunately, [Unity's solution](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InverseKinematics.html) is only listed to work with humanoid models, so you may have to create your own. Since the legs only have two joints and the parameters are fairly limited (ie. Touch closest point on ground), this might not be too much trouble - you may need to do some research on the theory though. (Alternatively, find an IK solver from the asset store.)